# Regex for <fixed-string><variable-string><fixed-string>?

Tags: .net, regex

I have a .NET solution in Visual Studio with a lot of projects, each of them containing an `AssemblyInfo.cs` with various copyright texts such as:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © Microsoft 2005")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2016")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © MyCompany 2014")]
```

I am looking to use the power of Regex to find all strings matching

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("<<variable>>")]
```

and replace it with

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © MyCompany 2017")]
```

What is the regex to match `<fixed-string><variable-length-string><fixed-string>` ?

I tried

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("(.*)")]
```

but it seems to be matching every character in the file.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and explain what it's not doing correctly.

Comment: @AndyLester: I am a noob at RegEx. I tried `[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("(.*)")]` but it seems to be matching every character in the file. I'm still trying as we speak.

Comment: Don't you know that `[` and `(` have special meaning in regular expressions, and need to be escaped if you want to match them literally? You clearly know that `(` is special, since you used it to create the capture group around `.*`. Yet you still tried to use it as a literal as well.

Comment: @Barmar: I'd tried `\[assembly: AssemblyCopyright\("(.*)"\)\]`as well. Didn't work.

Comment: Did you use `"..."` or `@"..."`? If you didn't use a verbatim string, you need to double the backslashes. This is why it's best if you post code, not just descriptions of what you wrote.

Comment: @Barmar: I was first trying [regexr](https://regexr.com) to write a Regex pattern that matched my test string. Didn't have it written out in code at that point.

Comment: Seems to work here: https://regexr.com/3ijin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162151/discussion-between-snag-and-barmar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://regexr.com/3ije4

```
var input = @"
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright(""Copyright © Microsoft 2005"")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright(""Copyright © 2016"")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright(""Copyright © MyCompany 2014"")]
";


var reg = new Regex(@"\[assembly: AssemblyCopyright\(""[^""]+""\)\]");
var result = reg.Replace(input, "[assembly: AssemblyCopyright(\"Copyright © MyCompany 2017\")]");
```

Explain:

**[^X]**  = any character other than X

**[^X]+** = one or more of any character other than X

**[^""]+** = one or more of any character other than " (double is for escape)

this is more specific, but .+ or .* also work.

Comment: This solution works but is missing an explanation. Can you explain how `[^\"]+` is working?

Comment: Any group (`[]`) of one or more characters (`+`)  that is *not* (`^`) a double quote (`\"`)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Barmar, I realized this works:

```
\[assembly: AssemblyCopyright\("(.*)"\)\]
```

Escaping the special Regex characters in the fixed strings and testing for the variable string using (.*) works perfectly.